# Ingesting Scrapy data to Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scrapy

I'm trying to load my scrapy data to elasticsearch so that I can do such search, I've actually succeeded in loading the data to an sql database, but with ElasticSearch I think I am missing something in my code:

in pipeline.py

```
def ingestForES(title: str, author: str,rank: int,description):
    es_url = es(hosts=[{'host': 'http://X.X.X.X', 'port': 9200}])
    es = es(es_url,basic_auth=("elastic", "Datascience"), verify_certs=False)
    data = {'title': title,
            'author':  author,
            'rank':rank,
            'description': description,
            } 
    resp = es.create(index='myindex', doc_type='mytype', body=data)
    print(resp)
```

I think I should add something inside settings.py, because with sqllite I have uncommented the following rule

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'amazon.pipelines.AmazonPipeline': 300,
}
```

I did a search and I found that I should also add in  settings.py:

```
 ITEM_PIPELINES = {
  'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline': 500
}

ELASTICSEARCH_SERVERS = ['http://X.X.X.X:9200']
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = 'myindex'
ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE = 'items'
ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY = 'url'
```

It's a little bit confusing to me, I am not that good with Scrapy but I am doing my best. So,please could anyone help me out with this and I will be gratefull. Thanks in advance.
Note: If you need extra information about the code I can share it.

Comment: any solution, any idea???

Comment: Are you using Amazon OpenSearch Service which is derived from Elasticsearch or a proper Elasticsearch?

Comment: yes, I pip installed elasticsearch, is that what you meant?

Comment: No, just doing `pip installed elasticsearch` doesn't mean you have an elastic search server or service for you to use. If you are using the Elasticsearch pypi package, I infer you are using Elasticsearch and not Amazon OpenSearch.

Comment: Aa , I understand now, yes I do have an elasticsearch up and running. because I once used webscraping using urllib and I succeded to parse the data into it. But, here with scrapy it's different, I have used all the ways but it's not wotking. I am confused.